Add Epson network printer to CUPS
Could somebody kindly tell me ho to add an Epson network printer, for which I installed the drivers, by CUPS (under WSL2)?
The printer URI, given by the printer backend itself, is https://192.168.1.6:631/ipp/print , but when I try to print I get the "filter failed" error.
The drivers are the official one.
The printer has been added by sudo lpadmin -p epson-xp6105 -v https://192.168.1.6:631/ipp/print -P /opt/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2/ppds/Epson/Epson-XP-6100_Series-epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2.ppd.gz -E.
Please, let me know if you know additional information.
Regards!
Edit: the error reported into the CUPS log is "Last OS error: Broken pipe", but telnet 192.168.1.6 631 works.

That's not a network protocol error – it's a job preparation error ("filter" being the core part of the printer driver), much before the network protocol gets involved. What if anything do you see in the CUPS service's logs?

I got from the printer itself the right url (https://192.168.1.6:631/ipp/print), and the CUPS error is: "Unable to open raster stream - : Broken pipe".

I found the solution:

The filter is located into /opt/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2/cups/lib/filter.
I discovered by ldd epson-escpr-wrapper2 that the libcupsimage.so.2 was missing.
I installed it by sudo apt install libcupsimage2.

Et voilà! :)

To add your Epson network printer via CUPS, try the following steps:

Open CUPS admin interface at http://localhost:631.
Go to "Adding Printers and Classes" and select "Add Printer."
Choose "Internet Printing Protocol (IPP)" and enter ipp://192.168.1.6.
Select the correct Epson driver.
If you get a "filter failed" error, ensure you have the latest drivers and that required dependencies are installed.

If issues persist, checking the CUPS error log (/var/log/cups/error_log) can provide more details.

I installed the latest official drivers from Epson website.

Please read to my edited post for further information. Thank you!

When you choose "Generic / Generic IPP Everywhere Printer" as driver there is no need to install any driver at all.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
